# Enumerate sites associated to a hub?

Tags: powershell, hub-site

I'm trying to list sites that are associated to a hub site from a PowerShell script. I'm using `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell`.

I tried :

```
Get-SPOSite -Filter "HubSiteId eq ""121c78fe-bd38-474a-b6a7-1a7be148e8e8"""
```

However it fails with :

```
Get-SPOSite : Syntax error in the filter expression 'HubSiteId eq "121c78fe-bd38-474a-b6a7-1a7be148e8e8"'.
```

What's the proper way to get these sites ?

I also tried :

```
Get-SPOSite -Limit all | ? { $_.HubSiteID -eq [guid]"121c78fe-bd38-474a-b6a7-1a7be148e8e8" }
```

Nothing is returned. It seems that HubsiteId is not retrieved as all sites have an empty guid with this command, whilst retrieving a single one shows the correct hubsiteid.

`-Detailled` switch didn't help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this module : "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" you can use : `Get-PnPHubSiteChild -Identity "URL of your hub site"`.

[Get-PnPHubSiteChild](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnphubsitechild?view=sharepoint-ps)